# Выгрузка string переводов в файл из android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio

В приложении есть несколько языков, три файлика с строками. Если смотреть в редактор переводов, то можно все переводы увидеть по трем языкам. Все ок, но возник вопрос - как можно выгрузить эти все переводы, например в какой-то файлик, табличку или еще как-то. У меня просто будет внедрятся еще 8 языков и переводчикам будет проще если будет табличка. Может есть возможность выгрузки в док, или все-таки придется все выписывать вручную. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: все эти переводы - простой текстовый файл в формате XML. и лежат они в папках соответствующих локалей, например для русского: res/values-ru/strings.xml

Comment: Да, я это знаю, но думал может в студии есть возможность экспорта

Comment: нет, возможности экспорта текстовых ресурсов в какой-нибудь .doc в студии нет.

Comment: очень жаль, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно так.

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на необходимый файл `strings.xml` и в выпавшем меню выберите `Open Translations Editor`. Выделите требуемые ячейки подобно выделению диапазона в таблице Excel. `Ctrl + C` и вставляйте, например, в таблицу Excel. Оттуда работа с данными будет по удобней.